# What manages IO between a buffer and a device?

Tags: cpu, buffer

If I am correct, a buffer is used as an intermediate between a CPU and a device,
to free the CPU from waiting for the IO with the device to complete, and to let the CPU do other things

Since the cpu is doing other things, it seems can't work to manage the buffer. What manages transfer data from the buffer to the device when the buffer is full, or take in data from the device when the buffer is empty?

Comment: The OS manages these I/O buffers for devices.  The OS (actually a device driver) would *initiate* a data-transfer operation if a buffer was full or empty.  The actual movement of data can be performed by the CPU (aka Programmed I/O or PIO), by a Direct Memeory Access controller (aka DMA), or by a Bus Master (similar to DMA but by a "smart" peripheral device on the system bus, e.g. a GPU on PCI).

Answer (score 1):

[Direct Memory Access (DMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) is the missing piece of your puzzle.  DMA lets I/O device controllers directly read and write memory without CPU intervention.

Without DMA, a buffer may still be employed as the data needs to live somewhere while it is being retrieved and it may be desired to only give data to the requesting program if the I/O completes successfully.

Comment: Thanks. What does ""only give data to the requesting program if the I/O completes successfully" mean? What is the opposite of "only give data to the requesting program if the I/O completes successfully"?

Comment: The I/O operation will take some time.  While this is happening other threads of the application may be running.  So the device driver involved may have the device DMA to a buffer it owns (not the application), and then copy (or return a reference to) the buffer to the application's memory space if the I/O is OK - if the device reports no errors or if the returned data is checksummed OK.  If an I/O error occurred, it may make sense for the driver not to pass invalid data to application.  Of course, take a look at some actual drivers, they may do different things.